# Magento configurable prices

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, product-prices

I have the following problem in my store. I've added some simple products to my configurable product but the prices are the problem. Only for one attribute the price is static. For the other it isn't, not even in percentage. So there's no way to add the correct prices. Is there a way to use the price of the simple product?

Comment: Hi Eddie, will you please clarify your problem with more data & screenshots (if possible)?

Answer (score 0):

No, not out of the box, but there are plenty of modules which do this for you, e.g.

- [Simple Configurable Products](https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple)

and Better Configurable Products, which does a lot more and affects the performance less.